# How to get a number from the div block using xPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Just recently started to study xPath.And I faced such a difficult task for me. I need to get it somehow here "22 973 ₴".How can I do this?

```
<div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow">
   <span style="color: #888888;"><strike>25 758₴</strike></span><br>22 973₴                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `xPath` to get value `22 973₴`

```
//div[contains(@class,'discounted')]/text()[2]
```

**Code**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//div[contains(@class,'discounted')]/text()[2]")).getText();
```

Comment: I am only studying xPath, so sorry for the stupid question.but isn't "//div[contains(@class,'discounted')]//br" does not find just a tag "br".Or I don't understand something ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python-Selenium`, you cannot use `text()` in **xpath** to make it work in `Selenium`, `Selenium uses xpath v1.0`

Please use below code :

```
price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow')]")
p = price.get_attribute('innerText').split('\n')
print(p[1])
```

Comment: OP asked same question again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399264/%d0%a0ow-to-get-multiple-values-at-the-same-timeusing-xpath 

Comment: @NandanA :  I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Yeah.. even I just saw that now..